# Win 10 PC with two NICs

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have Win10 PC which is part of corporate domain with two NICs installed. One NIC is connected to local network used for some alarm system (not needed to communicate to Internet) and second NIC is connected to corporate network configured for 802.1X.
PC uses VMware to start the OS and software for the alarm system. 
NIC connected to this alarm system has static IP 192.168.0.77/24 with no gateway configured, and NIC connected to corporate network has static IP 10.1.2.203/24 with default gateway configured.

The problem is that after reboot PC and WIN 10 automatically pick up the wrong IP address (192.168.0.77/24) and therefore PC is not accessible remotely over Internet. Workaround is to disconnect the cable for that NIC with IP (192.168.0.77/24) and reconnecting it again. Doing that gives me the right IP on NIC connected to corporate network.

Has anyone have idea how to configure this so that after reboot every NIC pick-up their IP address configured, so that I don't need to go there, disconnect the second cable and reconnect it again?

Comment: What you describe is not normal behavior. Windows will not mix up IP addresses between network adapters. What kind of network adapters are they (USB/PCI/...)? What make and model are they?

Comment: It's a brand PC HP 290 G2 MT Business PC with one Realtek NIC integrated to MBO, and other is Realtek PCI. At the moment I can't pick up the models because I cant access it over the Internet. I should go there and check which I cant do today. Maybe someday this week